# invoking only the required test in testng file while using ant

Tags: ant, testng, build.xml

I am trying to invoke tests of a testng.xml file from ant.

My testng.xml looks like the following:

```
<suite name="testsuite">
   bunch of parameters here
   <test name="test1">
   </test>

   <test name="test2">
   </test>
</suite>
```

Now, I want to run only the "test1" tests and not those of "test2". Is there a way (parameter?) to tell the ant build.xml file to do this?

```
<testng classpathref="testng.class.path" delegateCommandSystemProperties="true" 
            outputDir="${test-output}" haltOnfailure="false" useDefaultListeners="true" 
            parallel="methods"
            failureproperty="test.failure">
            <xmlfileset file="testng.xml"/>
            <!--forked JVM OOM issue-->
            <jvmarg value="-Xmx512M"/>
            <jvmarg value="-Xms512M"/>
            <jvmarg value="-Xmn192M"/>
            <jvmarg value="-XX:PermSize=128M"/>
            <jvmarg value="-XX:MaxPermSize=128M"/>

        </testng>
```

Answer (score 1):

Look up `-testnames` in the [documentation](http://testng.org) (note: plural).

Comment: Hi Cedric, thanks for the response. I couldnot find the -testnames in the documentation. Could you provide an example on how to use it or pass the value through this parameter

Comment: Really? It's right there in the "Running TestNG" section:  -testnames A comma separated list of test names. Only tests defined in a <test> tag matching one of these names will be run.

Comment: Hi I actually found it and used it yesterday..But it didnot work. it basically ran all the <test></test> blocks in the testng file. Not sure if i am using it in the right way. Could you please help me by giving an example..

Answer (score 0):

The xml files are there for exacly that: not running all tests from a class file containing tests. As I see it, the intended way to go would be to change the existing xml file, or create a new one.

Still, if your tests are included in different class files (I cannot see this from your example code), you could specify a classfileset instead of an xmlfileset, e.g.:

```
<testng  workingDir="../../" outputdir="${output_dir}" 
                verbose="2" listeners="org.uncommons.reportng.HTMLReporter,org.uncommons.reportng.JUnitXMLReporter"
                classpathref="testsClasspath">
                <classfileset dir="./${test_classes}/com/my/organization" includes="MyTest.class" />
            </testng>
```